# Bluetooth speakers appears and disappears on searching for devices to connect

Tags: sound, 16.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have an Wren V5US bluetooth speakers which was working fine with my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I restarted my system yesterday and it doesn't connect automatically anymore. I feel like I might have made some changes (mostly likely with pulseaudio) when I initially set it up to get it to work but I don't remember any more (and it could have been before upgrading to 16.04).

When I use the bluetooth manager it shows the speaker for a second or two before disappearing. This keeps repeating. I have *bluetoothctl* running and it keeps logging these lines:

```
[NEW] Device 00:17:53:73:95:DC V5US14_7395DC
[CHG] Device 00:17:53:73:95:DC Connected: no
[DEL] Device 00:17:53:73:95:DC V5US14_7395DC
```

I also have blueman-assistant running and it logs the following messages:

```
on_device_created (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:253)
created /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
__init__ (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py:26)
caching initial properties 
_________
add_device (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:317)
adding new device 
_________
do_cache (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:496)
Caching new device 00:17:53:73:95:DC 
_________
monitor_power_levels (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:185)
starting monitor 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
on_device_property_changed (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:163)
list: device_prop_ch Connected 0 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
RemoveDevice (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:427)
<Device.Device object at 0x7fe5053a3438 (blueman+main+Device+Device at 0x17b6740)> 
_________
__del__ (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py:72)
deleting device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC 
_________
Destroy (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py:94)
invalidating device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_17_53_73_95_DC
```

There many threads with similar problems but I am not sure which one applies to me. I did not want to go around trying all of them and messing up my settings.

**Edit 1**
You can find the pulseaudio [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Lzx9z0cDyyMVBZSkdOclc4UkU/view).